# Python 3.4: Where is the image library?

Tags: image, python-3.x

I am trying to display images with only builtin functions, and there are plenty of Tkinter examples online. However, none of the libraries work:

```
import Image  # none of these exist.
import tkinter.Image
import _tkinter.Image
etc
```

However, tkinter *does* exist, a hellow-world with buttons worked fine.

I am on a MacBook pro 10.6.8 and using PyCharm.

**Edit: The best way so far (a little slow but tolerable):**

Get the pixel array as a 2D list (you can use a third-party .py to load your image).
Now you make a data array from the pixels like this (this is the weirdest format I have seen, why not a simple 2D array?). This may be sideways, so you may get an error for non-square images. I will have to check.

Imports:

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter

data = list()  # the image is x pixels by y pixels.
y = len(pixels)
x = len(pixels[0])
for i in range(y):
    col_str.append('{')
    for j in range(x):
        data.append(pixels[i][j]+" ")
    data.append("} ")
data = "".join(data)
```

Now you can create an image and use put:

```
# PhotoImage is builtin (tkinter). 
# It does NOT need PIL, Pillow, or any other externals.
im = PhotoImage(width=x, height=y)
im.put(col_str)
```

Finally, attach it to the canvas:

```
canvas = tkinter.Canvas(width=x, height=y)
canvas.create_image(x/2, y/2, image=GLOBAL_IMAGE)  # x/2 and y/2 are the center.

tK.mainloop()  # enter the main loop and it will be drawn.
```

**Image must be global or else it may not show up** because the garbage collector gets greedy.

Comment: You might not have the [Python Image Library](http://www.pythonware.com/products/pil/) installed. It's not part of the standard distribution. There used to be a builtin library [imageop](https://docs.python.org/2/library/imageop.html), but it was deprecited in 2.6 and removed completely in python 3 because eveyone uses PIL.

Comment: I would recommend `pillow` over `PIL`.

Comment: Installing it on macintosh for my simple task just proved too much of a hassle.

Answer (score 2):

PIL hasn't been updated since 2009, with Python 3 support being terminally stuck at "later."

Instead, try [pillow](http://pillow.readthedocs.org/en/latest/), which has forked PIL and provides Python 3 support.

Comment: Yeah, but only up to 3.3. I see nothing for 3.4 at all.

Comment: http://pillow.readthedocs.org/en/latest/installation.html "Pillow >= 2.0.0 supports Python versions 2.6, 2.7, 3.2, 3.3, 3.4"